# Elasticsearch: Check dynamic mapping type

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve the mapping for an index as follows:

```
GET /twitter/_mapping/_doc
```

However there is no `dynamic` field for me to check whether the dynamic mapping type applied (`strict` / `false` / `true`).

How can I verify my `dynamic` mapping type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation on `dynamic` field mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#dynamic-field-mapping), if the `dynamic` setting is not specified (hence not returned by the `_mapping` call), the default value is `true`, which means that new fields will be created in the mapping if they don't exist yet.